# Uniform continuity of $\cos(x^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

I'm trying to figure out if the function $f(x)=\cos(x^2)$ is uniformly continuous in $\mathbb{R^2}$. Looking at it's graph It doesn't look like it is, as its graph oscillates more and more violently between $-1$ and $1$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$.

However I've failed to give an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof of this. I've also tried to pick two sequences $\{x_n\},\{y_n\}$ such that $\{x_n-y_n\} \rightarrow 0$ but $\{f(x_n)-f(y_n)\} \not\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: What if you take $x_n$ to be the points where $f$ takes its maximum 1 and $y_n$ to be the points where $f$ takes its minimum $-1$?

Comment: @DanielSchepler then $\{f(x_n)-f(y_n)\} \rightarrow 2 \neq 0$. But how can we give them? The only sequences I can think of would be  $\{\sqrt{2\pi n}\}$ and  $\{\sqrt{2\pi n + \pi}\}$ , but its difference does not converge to zero.

Comment: Why not?  Hint: $x_n - y_n = \frac{x_n^2 - y_n^2}{x_n + y_n}$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Got it! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. Let $x=\sqrt{2k\pi}$. We show that if $$|\cos(x^2)-\cos((x+\delta)^2)|<\epsilon$$for some $\epsilon>0$ therefore we can make $\delta$ arbitrarily small by taking $x$ sufficiently large. We have $$|\cos(x^2)-\cos((x+\delta)^2)|=|1-\cos(2x\delta+\delta^2)|=2\sin^2(x\delta+\dfrac{\delta^2}{2})<\epsilon$$which means that $$-\sqrt{\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}}<\sin(x\delta+\dfrac{\delta^2}{2})<\sqrt{\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}}$$or $$-2\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}}<2x\delta+\delta^2<2\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}}$$by adding up $x^2$ to the sides of the inequality we have$$x^2-2\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}}<x^2+2x\delta+\delta^2<x^2+2\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}}$$which by rearranging means that $$\delta<\dfrac{2\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}}}{x+\sqrt{x^2+2\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}}}}$$(the other bound is negative and not considered). So we can make $\delta$ arbitrarily small by taking $x$ sufficiently large.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the derivative is continuous and its absolute value is not bounded from above.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's sufficient to disprove absolute continuity?  For example, what if you had a function where over each interval of $\pi$, you come closer and closer to $\sqrt{|\sin x|}$ but replace the singularities at $n\pi$ with a smaller and smaller $C^1$ spline?

Comment: The question is about uniform continuity, but your comment is correct nevertheless. However, I did not say it is enough in general, and I did not think it was. But it helps finding the candidate points. If $x_i- y_i$ tends to zero and the difference $|f(x_i)-f(y_i)|$ must stay above a fixed value $\varepsilon$, then the fraction $|\frac{f(x_i)-f(y_i)}{x_i-y_i}|$ tends to infiity, so $|f'(z_i)|$ must tend to infinity for some sequence $z_i$ with $y_i\leq z_i\leq x_i$.

Comment: Are you saying hints are not allowed? I wanted to point the author to the right direction, rather than spoonfeed them the answer. There was neither any criticism, nor any need for clarification.